# I want to play multiple audio files. So I created a function for it. But it can only play one audio.. How can I make it?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

I'm trying to make voiceAudio as a template so I can play multiple audios if I want. But currently I can play only one audio. If I bring two voiceAudio like I did in example below, one of them wouldn't play.

How can I make it work?!

###### loginPhone.ts

```
import {voiceAudio} from '../../src/common/utils/voice';

const LoginPhone = () => {
    const domNavigate = useDomNavigate();
    const {openKioskAlert} = useContext(KioskAlertContext);
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState([]);
    const {playAudio, stopAudio} = voiceAudio('login-phone');


    useEffect(() => {
        playAudio();
        return () => stopAudio();
    }, []);
```

##### utils>voice.ts

```
export const voiceAudio = (title: string) => {
    const audioFile = new Audio(`/sounds/${title}.mp3`);
    const playAudio = () => audioFile.play();
    const stopAudio = () => {
        audioFile.pause();
        audioFile.currentTime = 0;
    };
    return {
        playAudio,
        stopAudio,
    };
};
```

##### what I would like to do  : example

```
import {voiceAudio} from '../../src/common/utils/voice';

const LoginPhone = () => {
    const domNavigate = useDomNavigate();
    const {openKioskAlert} = useContext(KioskAlertContext);
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState([]);

// if I bring bring?!two voiceAudio, one of them wouldn't work..
    const {playAudio, stopAudio} = voiceAudio('login-phone);
    const {playAudio, stopAudio} = voiceAudio('login-pin);


    useEffect(() => {
        playAudio();
        
        return () => stopAudio();
    }, []);

    const play =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are trying to use the same variable names multiple times. Notice how `playAudio` and `stopAudio` are being used twice. This is similar to writing `const a = 8; const a = 5`.

Try using different names for the second `voiceAudio` like this:

```js
    const {playAudio, stopAudio} = voiceAudio('login-phone');
    const {playAudio: playAudio2, stopAudio: stopAudio2} = voiceAudio('login-pin');
```

That will allow you to refer to the `playAudio` on the second line as `playAudio2` and refer to the `stopAudio` on the second line as `stopAudio2`.

In your `useEffect` you should then be able to freely call both functions like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        playAudio();
        playAudio2();
        
        return () => {
           stopAudio();
           stopAudio2();
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much for your precise and quick answer. I never thought I could refer to something..  I learn a valuable knowledge today! Thanks again!!